# Behringer x32 Out 1-16 levels

Tags: volume, multichannel, behringer

I'm using a Behringer x32, and I have OUT 1 and OUT 2 assigned to MAIN R.  The sound and levels coming out of my main speakers are great, but I have OUT 1 run into my Cannon Video Camera and the audio is quieter. Cannon Output Volume is cranked to it's highest.

2 questions:

1. Can I merge Main L and R and have them both go out of OUT 1
2. Can I independently control gain or volume on the OUT 1-16 channels?

Answer (score 2):

1. I think so, yes. Route both L and R to one matrix bus, and assign that to Out 1.
2. That depends on how you provide a signal to the Out port: Out 1-16 is just the output assignment. You set the volume on the channel that feeds the output. This can be the mains, but also any of the buses, an Aux bus or a matrix.

You're comparing apples and oranges:

- volume through your speakers has to be "loud enough" for the room. This is mostly unrelated to the maximum volume that can be produced by the console; you can use the amplifier to adjust the speaker volume.
- the camera input needs a certain level.

As you've discovered, you need to be able to control room volume and camera input level independently. There are several ways to do this.
The simplest is to route the Mains to a matrix, and assign that matrix to Out 1.